# Not able to access any camera in cv2.VideoCapture()

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I tried looping through all the camera ports from 0 to 100, but none of them seem to work. I tried with my laptop cam as well as obs cam. I am working on this for days.

This is my code so far:

```
#video feed
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
```

Comment: In the snippet you wrote you are just showing us the cap. Can you please log the `cap.isOpened()` in a for loop and print out what it is giving?

Answer (score 0):

try the same code with this range, it may work for you

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```